# Android KitKat (4.4.2) MediaPlayer OnCompletion() never called

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-4.4-kitkat

I am having a problem with the MediaPlayer on devices running android version 4.4.2.

Situation:
I want to run the MediaPlayer once, then decide in the onCompletion, if I want to play the sound again or not.

Problem:
* The mediaPlayer just keeps playing for ever
* onCompletion is never called
* Calling release and setting the mediaPlayer to null does not stop it either

I have read, that there is a bug in the 4.4 android versions. (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59185) does anyone know, if this is corrected? Is there an alternative?

Any ideas, suggestions and answers would be very welcome!

Here is some of my code:

```
public void start(){
    Uri uri = getRingtoneUri(this);         
    try{
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, notificationSound);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,  notificationSound);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    }catch(IOException e){
        log("onStartCommand", "notification Sound could not be loaded: ", e);
    }
}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    log("onComltion", "stop: " + stop);
    // do something
    }



public void stop(){
    mediaPlayer.release();
    mediaPlayer = null;
    }
```